# C# How do I know what a method returns if the return type is "object"?

Tags: c#, object

So how do I know what to expect from a method that has object return type. 
For example:

```
static object ReturnSth()
    {
        return "Some random text";
    }
```

This method is marked as a method that returns object. But inside of it you can see that it returns a string literal. The IntelliSense won't even show that it returns string it only knows that the method is returning an object. What do you do in such a case?

Also where are the string literals coming from? Are they from the System.Object or they are from "System.String"? Because It seems illogical to return something that System.Object doesn't have. (The string literal in this case)

Comment: You can utilize `Object.GetType Method ()`

Answer (score 2):

When a method returns `object`, you cannot make any assumptions about the type of return value. Even if you know that the current implementation returns a `string`, you can't simply call `string`s methods on the return result without a cast.

If you want to operate on strings returned as objects, cast them after a check, like this

```
object obj = ReturnSth();
string str = obj as string;
if (str != null) {
    Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
}
```

In C# 7 you can also use pattern matching on the type:

```
switch (ReturnSth()) {
    case string str:
        Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
    break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is not my best language, I prefer Java, but this is an object-oriented question.
 In Object-oriented languages, all things are object so all thing extends Object when you said that your method returns an object so this method can return anything that extends od object so your method can return anything, who call your method won't know what exactly this is return, they probably will cast the return to some other class like String or number, this approach like a code smell because you can get a cast error at runtime, the better way is to declare exactly what your method should return.

Comment: But are the string literals defined in System.Object? I think they are if i am able to return a string literal without any problem

Answer (score 1):

> how do I know what to expect from a method that has object return type.

You expect that it returns a type `object` and whatever *that* type provides.

This is the "surface contract" of the return value that you define.

In your case, it means that you won't be able to use any `string`-specific methods of the return value without an explicit downcasting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried coding that yourself in visual studio? The IDE would provide you an error at compile time.

Comment: This is not an answer. You can add comments once you hit 50 rep.